# JAVA AppEngine Remote API Standalone Client - How do I change the log level?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are using AppEngine's [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) with an internal support tool we have.
It is slow, and I seems like its because it sends all the Logs over the wire with LogLevel=TRACE. 
Can we change it to send only LogLevel=INFO somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well our bad. Apparently all we had missing was a log4j.properties file at the root of the project.